# Could not find or load main class, when running spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm having issues when I run my application as a java application.
I've tried various solutions but with no success.
I still get the following message:

> Could not find or load main class com.alliacom.audit.AuditApplication

This is the pom.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.alliacom</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>audit</name>
    <description>Alliacom auditing tool</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>lightadmin-nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://lightadmin.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.alliacom.audit.AuditApplication</mainClass>
  </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is my main application,
`AuditApplication.java`

```html
package com.alliacom.audit;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class AuditApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(AuditApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The project seems fine,
there are no errors during build,
but I don't see the cause of the problem.

Comment: what if you update to spring-boot-starter-parent latest version **2.0.1.RELEASE** ?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution, since your pom is very small:

- Got to **Spring Initializer**: https://start.spring.io/
- Generate a new **Maven / Java / SpringBoot 2.0** project.
- run it and check your system is fine
- start adding your customizations one at a time, and try after each modification.

In few minutes you'll have found the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the following from your pom file (it is not needed):

```
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.alliacom.audit.AuditApplication</mainClass>
</configuration>
```

Comment: i remove those following, after that i update the "Maven", and still same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the plugin like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```